# Importing all variables from a flexibly defined module

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

I have a main `config.py` file and then specific client config files, e.g. `client1_config.py`.

What I'd like to do is import all variables within my `client1_config.py` file into my `config.py` file. The catch is I want to do this flexibly at runtime according to an environment variable. It would look something like this:

```
import os
import importlib

client = os.environ['CLIENT']
client_config = importlib.import_module(
    '{client}_config'.format(
        client=client))
from client_config import *
```

This code snippet returns the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client_config'`

Is it possible (and how) to achieve what I'm trying to do or Python does not support this kind of importing at all?

Comment: Is the client modules dir in `sys.path`? And which line throws the error?

Comment: @CristiFati the last line returns the error

Comment: If your module is `client1_config.py`, then it makes sense that it wouldn't be able to find module `client_config` (missing the 1). Try printing `$CLIENT` or `client_config` before using them to make sure they look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `import_module` already imports the client configuration. `from client_config import *` assumes that `client_config` is the name of the module you are trying to import, just as `import os` will import the module `os` even if you create a variable `os` beforehand:

```
os = "sys"
import os  # still imports the os module, not the sys module
```

In the following, assume that we have a `client1_config.py` which just contains one variable:

```
dummy = True
```

To add its elements to the main namespace of `config.py` so that you can access them directly, you can do the following:

```
import importlib

client = "client1"

# Import the client's configuration
client_config = importlib.import_module(f"{client}_config")
print(client_config.dummy)  # True

# Add all elements from client_config
# to the main namespace:
globals().update({v: getattr(client_config, v)
                  for v in client_config.__dict__
                  if not v.startswith("_")})
print(dummy)  # True
```

However, I would suggest to access the client's configuration as `config.client` for clarity and to avoid the client's configuration file overwriting values in the main configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for this, works a treat! I had never seen f-strings before either. Love it!